# Refresh the dropdown options whenever a user click on the dropdown list

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

I have created a simple dropdown with html and php/mysql

```
<select name="location_id" id="location_id" class="form-control">
 <?php
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM locations";
   $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql); 
   while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ ?>

      <option value="<?php echo $row['location_id'];?>">
       <?php echo $row['location_name'];?></option>             
 <?php } ?>
</select>
```

It is working great until a new record is inserted from another page. I need to refresh the page to get the newly inserted record in the dropdown.

In my current application I need to refresh the dropdown options without refreshing the whole page whenever a user click on the dropdown list. The options should be fetched in realtime from the mysql database.

I have searched for the solution, but not able to find the similar solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To refresh only a part of a page you need to use JavaScript, AJAX to be specific.

Ajax lets you send HTTP requests and update page elements without a full page reload.

You could try something like this

```
<script>
function refresh_items() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
  document.getElementById("location_id").innerHTML =
  this.responseText;
}
};
xhttp.open("GET", "refresh_list.php", true);
xhttp.send();
}
</script>

<select name="location_id" id="location_id" class="form-control" onclick="refresh_items();">
</select>
```

Now that you've made your client side scripts you want you server side PHP on `refresh_list.php` to look something like this

```
 <?php
   //all your SQL settings and stuff here
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM locations";
   $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql); 
   while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ ?>

      <option value="<?php echo $row['location_id'];?>">
       <?php echo $row['location_name'];?></option>             
 <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked great for me, however just need to add a new line in the javascript to initialise the variable 

`var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();`

Comment: Once again help needed, the above code works great on most of the browsers, but not on Safari, any possible causes?

Comment: It doesn't load the options in Safari, I checked on console, no error found.